# How to Insert system date with other data with Angular in Asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular

here is js code code for insert data...

```
$scope.saveTask = function () {
        debugger
        $scope.submit = 'Saving..'
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: $scope.MyData
        })
    };
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="MyData.DataDesc" name="" />
<input type="text" ng-model="MyData.DataDate" name="" />
```

How can put system date on "MyData.DataDate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the value,

```
 $scope.MyData.DataDate =  new Date();
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to show it on as a default value on text box, but works only when saving the task

Comment: Just assign the value inside the controller initially. Then it will work

Comment: you need to declare like this $scope.MyData = {}; and then $scope.MyData.DataDate =  new Date();

Answer (score 0):

As @sajeetharan, already given the answer. `Date` Object creates instance according to system setting.

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings.

See here for more detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date